# Authenticating and using iAM users to access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

My use case is to allow users to create new user/password, create a folder for each user and allow them to upload files.

Then when they come back, they can login with the user/password and download their files (which are used within our product)

I managed to get most of the staff done using the C# API - very happy!
The only problem is that I cannot find a way to authenticate the user with IAM - using the username/password.

I don't want the end user to worry about key/secrets and long strings, they are suppose to be able to transfer these details (and access to data files) with other users to help them.

Is there a way to authenticate an IAM username/password?  Thanks, Uri.

Comment: I assume you meant username/password via the console?  So this didn't sem to be a C# or API question.  Sorry if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'federated access' - with that you have users with accounts and passwords on your system. Then they authenticate with your system, and you grant them access for up to 36 hours through a session based system (encrypted cookie, or memcache etc) to have access to their folder.

You can do this with a web application or with a standalone C# windows app that authenticates to your server.

With a web app, your users log in, user/pass, then you store an encrypted cookie or similar, so that your web app can make pre signed posts, download files, etc while they are logged in. There is no need for them to ever see an AWSID/Secret.

Comment: That's what I figured, AWS does not allow to authenticate users.

Comment: What I've ended up doing, was to store the username/password/key/secret on my database/server and authenticate locally - it was actually very simple to do.

Comment: You can encrypt the aws info with the users password. Since you also store the password hash only, you then will have a db, which if stolen will only give the thief some salted hashes and some encrypted stuff, along with their usernames.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, this seems to be available.  You just need to have them log into the console from the sign-in link provided on the AWS IAM homepage.

[image: IAM console sign-in link]

You will then need to assign a password to the user account in question and add a policy for them so they can access the S3 bucket in question.  You need the list all my buckets to get past the first screen of the console.  I just tried it and something like the following works:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1363222128",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt136328293",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to use the key/secrets. That is the short answer. When you create a new user in IAM it will give that specific user their own key/secrets. All they need to do is login, grab their key/secret and punch it in.

> Manage IAM users and their access - You can create users in IAM,
>   assign users individual security credentials (i.e., access keys,
>   password, Multi Factor Authentication devices) or request temporary
>   security credentials to provide users access to AWS services and
>   resources. You can manage permissions to control which operations a
>   user can perform. - aws.amazon.com/iam